# Can I grant permanent access to external storage to an app in Nougat?

Tags: applications, external-sd, permissions, 7.1-nougat

I'm using OnePlus 5 running stock 7.1.1.

I use the OTG function to transfer file between my phone and my flash drive very often, and my preferred file manager is Root Explorer. Every time I try to copy stuff to flash drive, I must first grant it access.

Can I permanently grant Root Explorer access to external storage? I don't mind messing around with system configuration files (like `packages.xml`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Manually granting permission

For rooted devices, there is a way to inject a specific permission inside the `/data/system/packages.xml` file, which details any and all installed apps, alongside their signatures and permissions.

The permission mentioned above is `<item name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" granted="true" flags="0" />`, which is usually granted to system apps only. This line must be added under the `<perms>` node of the package name one wishes to grant permanent access to the external storage, be it an SD card or a drive attached via OTG.

For Android to acknowledge the new permission, **a reboot is needed**.

### Revoking permission

To revoke the abovementioned permission, one just needs to remove the `<item name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" granted="true" flags="0" />` line they themselves added.

### Automated alternatives

If one does not want to manually edit `packages.xml` but has Xposed, it is possible to achieve a similar result by using the `XInternalSD` module. Upon activating it, enter its settings and disable any checkbox but the one next to `Full access to external SD card`.

This, depending on the Android version in use, is able to grant read-write access to external media. It is tested and running up to Nougat 7.1.2. **This method is not granular, hence any app will be able to access any external media.**

I am not affiliated to either XInternalSD, or to its developer.

Comment: I agree for sure.

Comment: I edited the packages.xml for an app called Termux, as per your suggestion but I still can't write to the  External SD card from the app. I am not really familiar with Xposed and would rather not go down that road. Any other suggestions?